# Multiple formula in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table with multiple cells. I am trying to get a formula working according to the following:
If Cell A is empty then Cell D has to be empty
But if A is a number then I need to check what is in  Cell B to calculate Cell D 
(if Cell B = "TOP",Then Cell D= cell C*170) Or If Cell B="BAR",OR ="CAR", OR ="DAR", Then Cell D = Cell C*170)

Comment: Your separating `B="TOP"` from the other options but the result is the same: `C*170`

Answer (score 0):

In cell "D1"

```
=IF(A1="","",IF(B1="TOP",C1*170,IF(OR(B1="BAR",B1="CAR",B1="DAR"),C1*170,"NOT FOUND")))
```

---

[image]

---

Check if A is a number:

```
=IF(A1="","",IF(ISNUMBER(A1),IF(B1="TOP",C1*170,IF(OR(B1="BAR",B1="CAR",B1="DAR"),C1*170,"NOT FOUND")),"Not Number"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a nested IF statement to go in cell `D1`. It looks like your doing the same calculation whether `B1="TOP"` or your other list of variables for `B1` so you can just put them all in the same OR statement. Something like:

```
=IF(A1="","",IF(ISNUMBER(A1),IF(OR(B1="TOP",B1="BAR",B1="CAR",B1="DAR"),C1*170,"A1 is number, B1 not in list"),"A1 not a number"))
```